# Should “by” be capitalized before the author's name on a cover page?

Tags: capitalization

If creating a cover page for a draft, should the *by* in the following format be capitalized? Microsoft Word seems to think so, but it looks visibly appealing when it is lowercase.

> Underlined Title Name
>    by Firstname Lastname

or

> Underlined Title Name
>    By Firstname Lastname

Comment: Spell/grammar check does not realize you are writing a title and a *by* line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Word only thinks so because it is incompetent at design. It says anything which starts a new paragraph (= after a carriage-return) must be capitalised.

Now, normally, that is indeed the case. But **this** case is about design, not grammar. It's akin to the shortening of newspaper headlines by missing the main verb: there is a particular style applicable to a particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

The 'by' should be lower case.  Microsoft word is only telling you to make it a capital letter because you started a new line, and it's assuming that it's a new sentence.

This is assuming a certain style guide, but it may vary depending on which one you are using.  Some guides would encourage capitalizing "By" instead.

Answer (score 0):

The second line is not part of the title, but of the *[byline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byline)*; title style does not apply. Microsoft Word's "grammar" checker is, like all similar machine solutions, primitive; it does not detect that you are not starting a sentence.

Whether or not to capitalize the *by* in the byline, or omit it altogether, and in what contexts (e.g. research paper cover page as opposed to a magazine article), depends on the style guide you are using. There is no single convention to strive for other than consistency.

For what it's worth, *The New York Times* always capitalizes *by*, as does the *Los Angeles Times*, the *Washington Post*, and *The Wall Street Journal*.